# Creating a Simple Database with UI on Local Machine

Tags: web-apps, database, sql, user-interface

I am looking to create a small database (no more than 6 tables with less than 10000 records) which can be accessed from a front end GUI which will present records to the user along with forms to create new records.

However, the database itself will need to be locally stored and not use a server to  process requests. Ideally, the front end would be able to run procedures in the database without an intermediate application. The database ideally would support 2-3 users at once but this is not a requirement. NoSQL and SQL approaches are both acceptable however I am better versed with SQL.

I have been looking at a way to use HTML and JavaScript as my front end, although I am not limited to those languages. As for the database, ideally a single file like a .mdb or .accdb file would be used.

In summary, I am looking to build a user friendly interface for a database that can run on any computer, even from a USB drive. Is there some software that might be able to help me achieve this elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is a single-file database that may be suitable for your application.  It has good support for SQL (it tracks Postgres pretty well), but is lacking stored procedures or functions.  Its performance isn't comparable to client-server systems, but for a small low-load applications, it can be just fine.

The SQL.js library (https://github.com/kripken/sql.js) can be used to work with a SQLite database on the front end.

Comment: SQLite does look promising however my main problem is getting Javascript (or some other front end language) to read and write data from/to the file.

Comment: Edited answer to include a reference to SQL.js.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to download MySQL to the desktop and use Microsoft PowerApps as its frontend software to modify data.  MS PowerApps is subscription based and its price is relatively inexpensive.